# Strip HTML tags and attributes except allowed in TSQL

Tags: html, sql, t-sql

Is there any function or procedure that allows to strip only not allowed attributes and tags from html text in MSSQL ?

for example allowed elements are:

```
a[href|target=_blank],strong,b,div[align],br,p[align|class]
```

or something like that

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to write your own function to do that.  But you might want to start with the example below taken from this [popular SQL Server blogger](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/16/sql-server-udf-user-defined-function-to-strip-html-parse-html-no-regular-expression/).  You'd have to modify it to ignore tags in your "allowed" list since as it is right now it nukes anything in '<' '>' tags.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_StripHTML](@HTMLText VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Start INT
DECLARE @End INT
DECLARE @Length INT

SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1

WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0    
BEGIN
   SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
   SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
   SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
   SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
END

RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))

END
GO
```

Needless to say however the more variety of tags you'd allow the more complex the tsql would be.  My guess is that there are 3rd party tools that would do a better job in java, c#, or whatever other language your current app platform supports that would probably be a much better way to go.